# How to select item with index ListView

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

How to select item with index in ListView(Xamarin Forms)?
I try this

```
ObservableCollection<TabItem> _tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
_tabs.Add(new TabItem { Title = "Tab item" });
_tabs.Add(new TabItem { Title = "Tab item" });
_tabs.Add(new TabItem { Title = "Tab item" });

int selector = _tabs.Count;
ListView.SelectedItem = _tabs[selector];
```

But it doesn't work.
Help me please.

Thank you!
Best wishes.

Comment: what is the ListView's ItemsSource?

Comment: ` ObservableCollection<TabItem> _tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>(); `

Comment: what do you expect to happen when you manually set the SelectedItem?

Comment: I resolve this issue

Comment: You can mark the answer which would help more people with same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ObservableCollection<TabItem> _tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
_tabs.Add(new TabItem { Title = "Tab item" });
_tabs.Add(new TabItem { Title = "Tab item" });
_tabs.Add(new TabItem { Title = "Tab item" });

int selector = _tabs.Count - 1;
ListView.SelectedItem = _tabs[selector];
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding 3 items to your collection, you end up with indices 0, 1, and 2 being populated.

Those are the only 3 numbers that you can use to access the collection at that point, so setting selector to Count property (which returns 3 after adding 3 items) results in trying to access element with index 3, which doesn't exist.

When working with collections, the last element you can access is always Count - 1 (unless it's empty).